# Manually Creating a JSON Schema Reference with JSchema

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I'm creating manual JSON schema using JSchema. Normally, I specify the attributes of a JSchema property like this:

```
JSchema props = new JSchema();
props.Properties.Add(KeyName), new JSchema { Type = JSchemaType.String });
```

However, for certain objects, I want the Property to be a reference to a property in another schema.  When I do this by hand, this works:

```
"text": {
  "$ref": "Common.json#/definitions/Text"
}
```

What I want to do is auto generate the above property using JSchema.  JSchema has a property called Reference, but I can't find any documentation on how to use it.  I've tried to do it this way:

```
props.Properties.Add("Text", new JSchema { Reference = new Uri("Common.json#/definitions/Text", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });
```

But no go.  What is the correct method for creating references using JSchema?

Comment: What's the result of the above code? Is there an error? Does it produce incorrect JSON (and if so, what does it look like)?

Comment: With this code, I get nothing.  No Text property at all in the schema.

Comment: The only example I can see is at https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CreateJsonSchemaWithReferences.htm but that doesn't explain how to do external references. Unless you have any specific reason, I'd build the JSON Schema files by hand, then load them in. I'm not a fan of "autogenerated class docs is documentation"... it's poor. If you've paid for it, contact their support directly.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I'm also trying to get a solution for this problem :/

Answer (score 1):

You can set $ref property like that

```
JSchema propertySchema = new JSchema();
propertySchema.ExtensionData["$ref"] = "Common.json#/definitions/Text";

schema.Properties.Add("Text", propertySchema);
```